# Android performance testing using "android.test.PerformanceTestCase" interface

Tags: android

I am trying to test performance of an android application using "android.test.PerformanceTestCase" interface , can anyone tell me how to make use of it...

I know i can use Traceview tool to test performance but i want learn to use "android.test.PerformanceTestCase" interface provided by android.

If i get any example code it will be very much helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Download](http://source.android.com/download) the Android source code and look in `frameworks/base/tests/AndroidTests/src/com/android/unit_tests`. You'll find a lot of `PerformanceTestCase` examples.

Answer (score 2):

I cloned the android source looking for the files suggested by Mirko's answer. The repository is very large and took me a while to clone. I searched it for all instances of *PerformanceTestCase* and found the following files which implement it:

#### [/base/graphics/tests/graphicstests/src/android/graphics](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/graphics/tests/graphicstests/src/android/graphics/)

- [*/GraphicsPerformanceTests.java:            implements PerformanceTestCase {*](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/graphics/tests/graphicstests/src/android/graphics/GraphicsPerformanceTests.java)

#### [/base/test-runner/src/android/test](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/test-runner/src/android/test)

- [*/TestRunner.java:public class TestRunner implements PerformanceTestCase.Intermediates*](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/test-runner/src/android/test/TestRunner.java)

#### [/base/core/tests/coretests/src/android/app/activity](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/tests/coretests/src/android/app/activity/)

- [*/ActivityTestsBase.java:        implements PerformanceTestCase, LaunchpadActivity.CallingTest {*](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/tests/coretests/src/android/app/activity/ActivityTestsBase.java)

#### [/base/core/tests/coretests/src/android/util](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/tests/coretests/src/android/util/)

- [*/LogTest.java:    public static class PerformanceTest extends TestCase implements PerformanceTestCase {*](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/tests/coretests/src/android/util/LogTest.java)

#### [/base/core/tests/coretests/src/android/database](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/tests/coretests/src/android/database/)

- [*/CursorWindowTest.java:public class CursorWindowTest extends TestCase implements PerformanceTestCase {*](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/tests/coretests/src/android/database/CursorWindowTest.java)
- [*/DatabasePerformanceTests.java:    public static class ContactReadingTest1 implements TestCase, PerformanceTestCase {*](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/tests/coretests/src/android/database/DatabasePerformanceTests.java)
- [*/DatabaseStatementTest.java:public class DatabaseStatementTest extends AndroidTestCase implements PerformanceTestCase {*](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/tests/coretests/src/android/database/DatabaseStatementTest.java)
- [*/DatabaseGeneralTest.java:public class DatabaseGeneralTest extends AndroidTestCase implements PerformanceTestCase {*](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/tests/coretests/src/android/database/DatabaseGeneralTest.java)
- [*/NewDatabasePerformanceTests.java:    implements PerformanceTestCase {*](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/tests/coretests/src/android/database/NewDatabasePerformanceTests.java)
- [*/DatabaseCursorTest.java:public class DatabaseCursorTest extends AndroidTestCase implements PerformanceTestCase {*](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/tests/coretests/src/android/database/DatabaseCursorTest.java)

#### [/base/core/tests/coretests/src/android/view](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/tests/coretests/src/android/view/)

- [*/CreateViewTest.java:public class CreateViewTest extends AndroidTestCase implements PerformanceTestCase {*](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/tests/coretests/src/android/view/CreateViewTest.java)
- [*/InflateTest.java:public class InflateTest extends AndroidTestCase implements PerformanceTestCase {*](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/tests/coretests/src/android/view/InflateTest.java)

Note that incase some of these change or are moved in the future, the commit hash I searched today was [ce7dba6bdf2345f39ad8f39b8a4c1bac9bcd35ea](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/ce7dba6bdf2345f39ad8f39b8a4c1bac9bcd35ea)